# toFixed in chrome broken?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I was breaking my head debugging the rounding in some application and it boiled down to this:

```js
(1.445).toFixed(2) // rounding as expected = 1.45
"1.45"
(85.485).toFixed(2) // what??? should be 85.49!
"85.48"
```

The number itself `85.485` can be displayed as such, so it doesn't seem a power of 2 float problem...

Any Idea why this is happening?

Comment: Like @JaromandaX said, be careful when using [`toFixed`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed) when dealing with numbers that need precision. Use [`toPrecision`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toPrecision)  instead.

Comment: @FF - toPrecision is not going to help

Comment: @JaromandaX care to elaborate?

Comment: Just avoid using floats or doubles if you need such precision. Use integers and trail as needed to avoid undesired results.

Comment: how would you use toPrecision in both cases ... 85.485.toPrecision(2) gives 85 ... oh, so it's total digits ... 85.485.toPrecision(4) gives .... 85.48 ... still haven't found what OP is looking for ... and then, you need to calculate the value for the argument based on the number of digits before the decimal point ... but, as mentioned the result still won't give the "expected" 85.49

Comment: To display formatted numbers nowadays, I recommend the `Intl.NumberFormat` constructor... `const formatter = new Intl.NumberFormat('en', { minimumFractionDigits: 2, maximumFractionDigits: 2 }); console.log(formatter.format(1.445));`

Comment: @FF- according to (this)[https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toPrecision] `toFixed` relies on `toPrecision`.

Comment: Number `85.485`does not exist. On scanning it is rounded to the nearest existing number `85.4849999999999994` (you can proof it with `(85.485).toPrecision(18)`). And rounding this number results in the correct value of `"85.48"` (a string, because the number does not exists!).